# Free 2D array columns

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc, free

I have a 2D array of strings, dynamically allocated with this:

```
char*** allocateArray(int line, int col)
{
    char*** dictionary;
    int i=0,j=0;
    dictionary=(char***)malloc(sizeof(char**)*line);
    for(i=0;i<line;i++)
    {
        dictionary[i] = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
            dictionary[i][j] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
    }
    return dictionary;
}
```

Now I want to free the last column (lets say), what should I do ?
I use `free(dictionary[i][j])`,  but what does it actually free ? The `[i][j]` cell in the array, or the pointer that it points to?
I need to free both.

Comment: I think you need five or six more `'*'`s. :-P

Comment: I didn't choose to do it this way, its an assignment and i must use char***

Answer (score 0):

`dictionary[i][j] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));` is wrong, you want to allocate space for a `char`, not a `char *`. You would free it like you would any other pointer, so `free(dictionary[i][j])` is correct.

Comment: dictionary[i][j] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)); is actually not wrong, its a 2D array of pointers=arrays=strings.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that you have to free memory in the reverse order you reserved the memory. In this case, it is correct to loop over `j` for freeing `dictionary[i][j]` (where the index `i` is fixed), because then you'd be freeing the space reserved for `*(*(dictionary + i) + j)`. After that you would loop over `i` for freeing `dictionary[i]` (which frees the space reserved for `* (dictionary + i`), and finally, you would just `free (dictionary)` (and you are freeing `* dictionary`).

Note: the order you free space does matter because if you free a block of memory that is actually pointing to another block of reserved memory, then you can't free this last one anymore, so you will have memory leaks. That's why you have to start to free memory in the reverse order you called `malloc`s.

Summarizing, this piece of code will work fine into yours (I tested it with Valgrind, and there is no memory leaks):

```
for (i = 0; i < line; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < col; j++){
        free (dictionary[i][j]);
    }
    free (dictionary[i]);
}

free (dictionary);
```

You can see an explained example of how to free a 2-D array [here](http://danielmbcn.wordpress.com/2013/07/07/some-notes-about-dynamic-memory-allocation-of-multi-dimensional-arrays/). I hope it can be useful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

The confusion is coming from the fact that the assignment is not clear to you.

- First, if `dictionary[i][j]` must point to a string, which is a `char *`, then `dictionary[i][j]` must be a `char **` because it is pointing to a pointer. Therefore `dictionary[i]` must be a `char ***` and dictionary must be a `char ****`.

On the other hand, if dictionary must be `char ***`, then each `dictionary[i][j]` must contain a char and not a `char *`, as stated by user3112989, so either one of your restrictions is wrong.

So, to answer your question, `free(dictionary[i][j])` would free the string it is pointing to, as long as you, somewhere else in your code do something like `dictionary[i][j] = pointer_to_string_i_j;`, but in that case you didn't have to allocate them since the data they are pointing to already has a memory block (if you took care of that).

- Second, avoid casting the pointers returned by malloc (unless your teacher asks you to, but you should discuss it with him). You can find here multiple discussions about why it is not necessary in C, and how it could potentially hide other problems.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: each pointer that was returned from `malloc` must eventually be passed to `free`.

The slightly longer answer: each time `malloc` is called, it allocates a contiguous block of memory and returns a pointer to that block. When `free` is passed that pointer, it returns the whole block of memory to the operating system. If you allocated 10 megabytes with `dictionary[i][j] = malloc(10000000)`, then `free(dictionary[i][j])` will free all 10 megabytes.

Since `dictionary[i]` is itself a pointer to a dynamically allocated memory block, you will also need to `free(dictionary[i])` -- *after* you have freed each string in `dictionary[i][j]`.

Answer (score 0):

Before thinking about freeing, we should make sure that `allocateArray()` is correct, which it isn't:

```
        dictionary[i] = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

The above statement allocates just one `char *`, only `dictionary[i][0]`.

```
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
            dictionary[i][j] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

Here all writes to `dictionary[i][j]` for *j > 0* access unallocated memory.

What you need instead of the above three code lines is:

```
        dictionary[i] = malloc(sizeof (char *) * col);
```

After this, memory for all strings (i. e. `char *`) is correctly allocated; there's no need to initialize it.

---

> Now I want to free the last column (lets say), what should I do ?

You must reallocate the memory for each line:

```
    --col;
    for (i=0; i<line; ++i)
        dictionary[i] = realloc(dictionary[i], sizeof (char *) * col);
```

Note that if you assigned dynamic memory to the character pointers in this last column, you must of course `free(dictionary[i][last])` *before* reallocating.