# Getting a Run-Time error when using free() in C

Tags: arrays, pointers, malloc, heap-memory, free

I'm using the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645264/free-2d-array-columns/20648588) to allocate a 2D array of strings (actually a 3D array) and after im done with it, i must free all the allocated memory, so I do it in reverse like this:

```
void freeArray(int col, int line, char*** dict)
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    for(i=0;i<line;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<col;j++)
            free(dict[i][j]);

        free (dict[i]);
    }

    free (dict);
}
```

But as soon as it gets to the 1st line with `free` in it, it crashes and the next messege appears:

> "HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after normal block (#67) at 0x00489890.
>   CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap
>   buffer.

To help you guys out, I must say that I have a feeling that I know where is the problem coming from, but don't know how to fix it because I don't understand pointers very well. For any word or definition added to the dictionary, i must allocate the exact size. so I used a function declared like this:`int inputString(char* p1, char* p2)`, and here is the call:`i+=inputString(dictionary[0][i],dictionary[1][i]);`. 
First I input the strings into buffers, and then I do this:

```
*p1=*(char*)malloc(strlen(wBuffer)+1);  
*p2=*(char*)malloc(strlen(dBuffer)+1);
```

I don't know, something about those two lines feels wierd, don't get me wrong thou, the dictionary works perfectly (except for `free()`) with those two lines.
What should I do ?
I'm using VS2012.

Comment: `*p1=*(char*)malloc(strlen(wBuffer)+1);` is potentially bad news. You are assigning to `*p1` a value whose address you just allocated, so it has no defined value yet. Also, note that you shouldn't typecast return values from `malloc`. Just assign them.

Comment: Yeah I know but my teacher insists on casting. But about the first part of what you said, what do you mean ? what should I do ?

Comment: From the little context you have in your question, I think you just want `p1 = malloc(strlen(wBuffer)+1);` and similarly for `p2`.